# Puppeteer - Way to pass elementHandles into a template literal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Is there a way to pass an elementHandle object into a template literal?

What I'd like to do:

```
const el = await (await page.$x('//div[@type='First']'))[0];
const divHeight = await page.evaluate(`${el}.scrollHeight`);
```

I know passing it as a function works but it would be a lot more elegant to do something like that as a string. Is there a way to convert an elementHandle to a DOM object reference?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there were some way to serialize that element (there may be, I don't know), does:

```
await page.evaluate(`${await someWayToSerialize(el)}.scrollHeight`)
```

feel more elegant than:

```
await page.evaluate(el => el.scrollHeight, el)
```

I think the function is more elegant every time.